# How to solve this Diophantine Equation. Step by Step

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What are all the solutions to the diophantine equation:
6x-6y-xy=0.

Comment: Like question, like answer... Here it is: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+diophantine+6x-6y-xy%3D0 (Press More solutions until you get all of them.)

Comment: Mily, you might find more favor with the local crowd if you show some of your own effort. As Bill has noticed, a good starting point is to add $36$ to both sides and factor by grouping.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I'm creating a program designed to solve Diophantine Eq. I just want to know how real solvers would react to a plain question, and yes, the solution is group the equation so that we have a product of two terms equal to 36. Then, by using prime decomposition , it'll be easy to find all possible solutions for integers values of x and y. Thank you all. Mily

Comment: You might be interested in emailing the author of [this Diophantine solver](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) for suggestions!

Comment: I presume that you are the user [who posted the question as well](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/29812/mily), so I flagged the moderators to merge the two accounts.

Comment: @Mily Why don't next time when you want to test something, instead of creating a new account and asking several similar questions in a row, you just tell people what your real problem is, and what you really want. This way, I believe, you will get more appropriate answers (I can't imagine how the two answers given here and for the other question might help to write the whole program solving Diophantine equations?!), and will also save some time for the moderators and others.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** $\ $ Rewrite it as $\rm\: (6+x)(6-y) = 36.$

Answer (score -1):

The 18 integer solutions are :

x = -42, y = 7

x = -24, y = 8

x = -18, y = 9

x = -15, y = 10

x = -12, y = 12

x = -10, y = 15

x = -9, y = 18

x = -8, y = 24

x = -7, y = 42

x = -5, y = -30

x = -4, y = -12

x = -3, y = -6

x = -2, y = -3

x = 0, y = 0

x = 3, y = 2

x = 6, y = 3

x = 12, y = 4

x = 30, y = 5